# C++: How-to create a simple program for moving folders

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that moves certain named folders (and all files contained) from directory A to directory B. It was suggested to code in C++. So I was wondering if anyone knew of a simple way to do this, if they could give me a link, and if anyone know's where it's possible to set the directories as variables that can be loaded from a text file. I'm asking this question, because I want to basically have all my program settings and whatnot from the appdata folder since I move between computers alot, be easily transferable.

settings.txt (This is an example of what I mean.)

```
fldrget = (Folder Name)
fldrdir = (Path to Folder)
fldrplc = (Folder Destination)
```

Would creating an xml document be a better idea as far as the txt document goes?

Additional Information: OS: Windows(XP, Vista, 7) and I'd like to make this a GUI, but as I'm not familiar with any C language, I'll settle for basics first if anyone can give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: What operating system? Please tag with the O/S name.

Comment: Are you familiar with C++?  If you aren't, then doing this in C++ may not be the best choice.

Comment: I updated my question with what you asked about. I'm using Windows XP, Vista, and 7 and I'm hoping to make a GUI, but I'll settle for less if I can't figure out anything. I'm not familiar with any C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a bit more information? Are you wanting to write a console application or a GUI? What platform are you targeting? You could use the Win32 API, Boost, Qt, Wx, or a number of others.

You may want to look into using PowerShell. It is much more friendly for a new comer and built-in to Windows 7 and freely available for Windows XP. Just do a google search for moving a directory using PowerShell to get started

Comment: I updated my question with what you asked about. I'm using Windows XP, Vista, and 7 and I'm hoping to make a GUI, but I'll settle for less if I can't figure out anything.

Comment: You may want to look into using PowerShell then. It is much more friendly for a new comer and built-in to Windows 7 and freely available for Windows XP. Just do a google search for moving a directory using PowerShell to get started. If you run into too much trouble, just let us know.

Comment: That sounds awesome. Thank you. If I have trouble, I'll be back.

Comment: Can you edit this so the answer is in the body of the answer instead of the comments?  Thanks.